# Yii2 - radioList choosing bindend to two different fields

Tags: php, yii2, radiobuttonlist

I have two radioList bindend to two different fields:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                     <?= $form->field($model, 'isGdo')->radioList([0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'])->label("Are you a distributor ?"); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5">
                    <?= $form->field($model, 'isProducer')->radioList([0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes'])->label("Are you a producer?"); ?>
                </div>
</div>
```

Now my aim is to refactor this and create a radioList with 3 options in which I can set both these properties.

I know that I can switching to a single field with 3 values, but there are a lot of checks in the program, so keeping these two fields separate could be better for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create A radio  3 radio buttons for showing with same name.

```
isGdo and isProducer
```

kept as hidden input field .
Write jquery code on above radio button and set that value on input box on basis of selection of radio button.

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'isGdo')->hiddenInput(['value'=>''])->label(false);
 echo $form->field($model,'isProducer')->hiddenInput(['value'=>''])->label(false);

 $form->field($model, 'publicattribute')->radioList([1 => 'yes', 0 => 'No'])->label(''); 


<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("input[type='button']").click(function(){

            var radioValue = $("input[name='']:checked").val();

            if(radioValue){

                alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
                 **insert that value on your condition in the hidden input field**
            }

        });

    });

</script>
```